# Split a string "b161c43" into two (b161 & c43) with powershell.

Tags: regex, powershell, split

I need a quick help on below

> Problem Statement: I have a String "b161c43" and would need to split
>   this into "b161" and "c43" in PowerShell.

I tried following commands but its not giving me the complete text

```
   'b161c43' -split '\D'  
    => Output as : 161 43   
    => But I need: b161 c43


Test Data: 
b69c123 
a1c1 
s4202z22
```

Comment: `'b161c43' -split '\B(?=\D)'`

Comment: Hello, I believe this is a well-formed question however I closed it as duplicate because it is a basic regex question that could be solved with some research. I recommend you read the linked question/answer, then [use a RegEx tester to test your pattern and the resulting splits](http://regexstorm.net/tester).

Comment: Thanks this helps.